# Sum negative factorials

Tags: special-functions, summation

Is it possible to get Mathematica to evaluate

```
Sum[1/Gamma[1 - a], {a, 0,ul}]
```

to 1 for all nonnegative integer values of ul ? In particular I would like to have it return 1 for

```
Sum[1/Gamma[1 - a], {a, 0,Infinity}]
```

but it returns "sum does not converge". The function 1/gamma ought to evaluate to zero for integer arguments <= 0. The summand is nonzero only for the single term a=0.

Comment: Certainly, `Sum[1/Gamma[1 - a], {a, 0, ul}]` sums to `1` for every positive integer `ul`, as does `Limit[Sum[1/Gamma[1 - a], {a, 0, ul}], ul -> Infinity]`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that.  I probably  did something clever like set ul=Infinity and forget to clear it before taking the limit.

Comment: `Sum[1/Gamma[1 - a], {a, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"]` or `Sum[1/Gamma[1 - a], {a, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Cesaro"]`